# React Native release apk on Android crashes 0.60.4

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I am working on a new react native project and used the latest version for the support of AndroidX. My App works fine perfectly on debug mode when connected to the development server both iOS and Android. But when I try to build a release apk on Android it crashes both on Emulator and Android device.

When I run `adb logcat *:E` here is what I get below:

```
08-02 17:19:36.343  1437  1463 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-02 17:19:37.046  3919  3940 E ReactNativeJS: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false)
--------- beginning of crash
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.fitwaze, PID: 3919
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: t is not a function. (In 't(c)', 't' is false), stack:
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@354:3111
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: map@-1
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@354:3090
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@371:312
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@340:151
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@6:58
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: d@2:876
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: global code@830:4
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime: 
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
08-02 17:19:37.056  3919  3941 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-02 17:19:37.057  3919  3940 E ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Here is my **package.json** dependencies below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-indicator": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

And then re build the APK and check if it stills being crashed.